# How to implement two php mysql queries and display in two tables?

Tags: php, html, mysql, class, oop

I want to query two tables and display each table in the same html page, I am using two php chunks each one for each query, when I use only one `<?php...?>` chunk in the page it runs perfectly but when using both chunks I get an `HTTP ERROR 500`.
My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...

<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
 echo "<tr>
    <th>R1</th>
    <th>R2</th>
    <th>R3</th>
    <th>R4</th>
    <th>R5</th>
    </tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
    function __construct($it) {
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;  border-right: 1px solid #000000; text-align:center;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    function endChildren() {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }
}

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT R1, R2, R3, R4, R5 FROM chispazo_numeros");
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>

<h2></h2>

<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
 echo "<tr>
    <th>R1</th>
    <th>R2</th>
    <th>R3</th>
    <th>R4</th>
    <th>R5</th>
    <th>MEDIA</th>
    <th>PRIMOS</th>
    <th>REP</th>
    </tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
    function __construct($it1) {
        parent::__construct($it1, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;  border-right: 1px solid #000000; text-align:center;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() {
        echo "<tr>";
    }

    function endChildren() {
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    }
}

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

try {
    $conn1 = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt1 = $conn1->prepare("SELECT R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, MEDIA, N_PRIMOS, REP FROM chispazo_libres ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    $stmt1->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result1 = $stmt1->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt1->fetchAll())) as $k1=>$v1) {
        echo $v1;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e1) {
    echo "Error: " . $e1->getMessage();
}
$conn1 = null;
echo "</table>";
?>

...
```

I don't know if repeating the connection is best practice, I tried putting the two php chunks in only one but it doesn't work.

Any advice will be grateful.

Comment: Is there any error messages?

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx only the http error 500

Comment: You have duplicate class `TableRows` there. Change one of them if you really need both

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx That works! Thanks. I am pretty sure there is a better way to do this but for the moment it works!

Comment: Hello @xxMrPHDxx I need a button to rerun the second php query tag, for now I put a button to reload all the page in order to rerun the second query. Can you suggest a way to rerun the particular php tag without reloading the entire page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can combine it with JavaScript and update the table separately. Also, I recommend you to create separate file & if I were you I will create an API for the table update. Sorry for the late reply btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two `TableRows` classes declared in the same php file. To get around this make the following changes.

- Rename first `TableRows` class to `class FirstTableRows extends ...`
- Rename second `TableRows` class to `class SecondTableRows extends ...`
- In the first `foreach` loop change the `new TableRows(...)` to `new FirstTableRows(...)`
- In the second `foreach` loop change the `new TableRows(...)` to `new SecondTableRows(...)`